# Finding unique combination that sums up the dataset using Python

Tags: python, combinatorics

I have this question from somewhere as an exercise to a data engineering test.

Given a collection of candidate numbers (C) and a target number (T), find all unique combinations in C where the candidate numbers sum to T.

Requirements:
**Each number in C may only be used once in combination.
C and T will always be a positive integer**

```
Example: find a target = 6 from a dataset of [3,5,6,1,2]. the solution is
- [3,1,2]
- [5,1]
- [6]
```

I only know that this is an Apriori Algorithm but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: No, it's not Apriori at all. Not data mining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations` to find the unique combinations of every possible size within your list. For example

```
from itertools import combinations

a = [3,5,6,1,2]
target = 6
result = []
for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
    combs = combinations(a, i)
    for c in combs:
        if sum(c) == target:
            result.append(list(c))
print(result) # Output [[6], [5, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Sorry, can I ask additional question? how can I not repeat the C in the result? for example C = [9,1,2,7,6,1,5] and target = 8 will return this result: [1,7] [1,2,5] [2,6] [1,1,6]. Since [1,7] and [7,1] is considered the same.

Comment: And would result would you expect instead?

Comment: with the code above I got [[1, 7], [2, 6], [7, 1], [1, 2, 5], [1, 6, 1], [2, 1, 5]]. While the exercise prohibit to return [1,7] and [7,1]. 
Either [1,7] or [7,1] is allowed.